# Why is my for loop not calculating the number of words correctly?

Tags: c++

So I am trying to create a program that reads a line of text and calculates the number of words in that line of text. My idea was to search for the number of spaces(' ') in that line of text and then add 1 to this number to get the word count.

For some reason, when I use getline it miscalculates this but calculates the length perfectly fine. See below for my code.

Can someone point me to where I am wrong here?

```
  #include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

//Our variable for the line of text
string n;

//Function Prototypes
void word_count(string n);
void letter_count(string n);

//Array for alphabet
char lower_case[26] ={'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
char upper_case[26] ={'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};

int main() {

    cout<<"Please enter a line of text:"<<endl;
    getline(cin,n);
    cout<<n.length()<<endl;
    word_count(n);
    //letter_count(n);

    return 0;
}

//Function to count the words
void word_count(string n) {
    int wordcount=1;

    for(int i = 0; i<=n.length(); i++) {
        if(n[i]=' '){
            wordcount++;
        }
    }
    cout<<wordcount<<"\t words"<<endl;
}
```

Comment: You increment the count for every space. But if there are multiple space between words. Or what about tabs etc. What about the empty string zero words you would return 1. I would also note that `operator>>` when reading into a string will read one word. Also a single `=` is an assignment not a comparison. You may want to use `==`

Comment: What about TAB characters and subsequently occuring blanks?

Comment: `int wordcount=0; std::istringstream strm(n); std::string word;  while (strm >> word) ++wordcount;`.  No need in checking for spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace
`if(n[i]=' '){` by `if(n[i]==' '){`

Since you are not using the comparator (==) hence it never enters the count increment logic area.

Comment: Actually, it would always enter it, and always increment.